# Can a person with less then 500 reputation get a custodian badge?

Tags: discussion, badges, review-badges

I am wondering when I got custodian badge even if I have only 304 reputation & never cross 500.

My Question is : Can a person with less then 500 reputation get a custodian badge?

Comment: You did, so yes.

Answer (score 9):

Users can always review suggested edits on their own posts. You did [the same](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2278/custodian?userid=2761097). You earned the badge for [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3963787).

Comment: That suggested edit is *horrible*.

Comment: but some time i also get an error that you have not sufficient reputation for review...

Comment: @PulahNandha Someone suggests an edit on *your* post. You give it the OK. That is the review. You can't, yet, review edits on other people's posts, because you need >2k rep

Comment: @PulahNandha Those probably not on your own post. If you go to the [suggested edits review queue](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits) you will get the same error.